# Material design list item color with MaterialComponents

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I read the Material Design's webpage.
I have a `Three lines List item`.

Main text with: `android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceSubtitle1"`

Body text with:  `android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceBody2"`

Yes, I'm still using the `MaterialComponent` theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Now I need to set the colors. Check the docs:
[image]

I can't understand it. `#00000099` ?
What is it? Is it `#99000000` ?

Please help me to set the color.

Is there any solution for the best color setting? I want to use the material rules! (Are there pre definied color for these?)

Thanks

Comment: these are 8 digits.. first 2 are for transparency and last 6 are RGB color

Comment: Yes, I know that. But in the docs, they start with two 0. Its equal with full transparent color. #00xxxxxx is transparent. I think they swapped the numbers

Comment: maybe.. transparency ranges from 00 to 99

Comment: No. Range from 00 to ff

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution for the best color setting? I want to use the
>   material rules! (Are there pre definied color for these?)

I think this is exactly what you're looking:

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
```

**And in Material Design:**

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
```

Use this for that caption `TextView` and this one:

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
```

**Material Design:**

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
```

For the title `TextView`.

**Subtitle in Material Design:**

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
```

The color they mentioned, means that it should be like that and it's actually an example of how the color should be but in Android, we have Caption & Body1 style so, I don't think if that would be necessary to add custom color for that (Specially, in Android).

Comment: I want to use MaterialComponents.Subtitle1 and it not definite the color

Comment: Added for both material design and appcompat + subtitle. Check my updated answer.